# Can SMOTE be used for non-binary classification?

Tags: python, dataset, smote

There is a class imbalance present in my dataset and I would like to balance the dataset. The dependent variable's features are (0,1,2,3,4). How do I make use of SMOTE, SMOTE-N, SMOTE-NC when if they're only used for binary or categorical data?

Comment: [Statisticians do not see class imbalance as much of a problem, and there is no need to use SMOTE to solve a non-problem.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he) It might help solve your problem if you say why you find the class imbalance problematic.

Comment: As far as I know SMOTE just generates synthetic data, so you can generate as many instances as you want for any number of classes. But I wouldn't recommend it.